# AWS Cognito: How Require Password for changing User Attributes or Delete User?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I was looking in the documentation and I can't find a way, to **require password** to change User Attributes or Delete user.
Maybe there is a way to check user password?

How can I achieve this, in Javascript preferable?

Comment: Users who sign up are by default required to change password. Are you saying you want to require users to change password after the first change?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for this is that, if you want to ask user for password in order to delete account you should go with the *Log In f*unctionality. If the Log in is successful your *delete account* process should continue.